# Unable to burn 2 DVDs

Tags: ubuntu, burning

Today I purchased 2 DVDs today of Sony company. I tried burning them with some s/w but failed. Please see below for the error log produced. I used Brasero Disk Burner of Ubuntu13.04.
Then I used different CD and it worked properly. Also earlier I had successfully burned the same s/w in different DVDs of Sony.
So, it's almost clear that the problem is with the 2 DVDs.
Still I would like to post the error log below so that one can confirm.

```
Checking session consistency (brasero_burn_check_session_consistency brasero-burn.c:1739)
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroBurnURI output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_LPVE6W.bin toc = none
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroBurnURI no burn:// URI found
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroLocalTrack stopping
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLocalTrack output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_7XUE6W.bin toc = none
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroLocalTrack no remote URIs
BraseroLocalTrack stopping
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage stopping
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroChecksumImage output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_K0TE6W.bin toc = none
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_input_type
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage Starting checksuming file /media/ravbholua/0E441C8F441C7BA1/Users/Ravi/Downloads/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso (size = 789884928)
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage Setting new checksum (type = 2) d1d8b7d13604bbe0416fc16dbe901297 ((null) before)
BraseroChecksumImage Finished track successfully
BraseroChecksumImage stopping
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn unsupported operation
BraseroLibburn deactivating
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_device
BraseroLibburn Drive (/dev/sr0) init result = 1
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_media
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_tracks
BraseroLibburn Setting multi 0
BraseroLibburn Setting burnproof 1
BraseroLibburn Setting dummy 0
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn burn_drive_convert_fs_adr( /dev/sr0 )
BraseroLibburn Writing
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_dangerous
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn burn_drive_is_enumerable_adr( /dev/sr0 ) is true
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn Async START UNIT succeeded after 0.1 seconds
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn mmc_set_streaming: end_lba=2298495 ,  r=11080 ,  w=11080
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn Allocating buffer via mmap()
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn dvd/bd Profile= 11h , obs= 32768 , obs_pad= 1
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn DVD pre-track 01 : get_nwa(0), ret= 1 , d->nwa= 0
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn SCSI error condition on command 2Ah WRITE(10): See MMC specs: Sense Key 4 "Drive error", ASC 44 ASCQ D9.
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn Libburn reported an error SCSI error on write(784,16): See MMC specs: Sense Key 4 "Drive error", ASC 44 ASCQ D9.
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_error
BraseroLibburn finished with an error
BraseroLibburn asked to stop because of an error
    error       = 1
    message = "SCSI error on write(784,16): See MMC specs: Sense Key 4 "Drive error", ASC 44 ASCQ D9."
BraseroLibburn stopping
Session error : SCSI error on write(784,16): See MMC specs: Sense Key 4 "Drive error", ASC 44 ASCQ D9. (brasero_burn_record brasero-burn.c:2856)
```

Comment: It sounds like the DVDs are not compatible with your drive. Were these DVD-R, DVD+R or DVD-/+R or maybe RW? See http://www.webopedia.com/DidYouKnow/Hardware_Software/DVDFormatsExplained.asp

Comment: I concur with Terdon's assessment too. I'd be inclined to try using `k3b` instead to burn with as well. I find it easier to use, but I don't think that's your problem here.

Comment: @terdon They were DVD-R. But how come that the DVDs aren't compatible now. Earlier I had burned the same type of DVDs (of Sony). I had prepared bootable DVDs (of Sony) for Ubuntu O.S. , gparted, etc. Now, I feel the need to make 1 more copy of these so that in times of need, I can use other copy if one fails. As the 2 DVDs I had purchased yesterday from one shop didn't work, I used another DVD (of Sony only) purchased from another shop a month back. But I surprised to see that this also didn't work. But how come Sony DVDs worked earlier (which were purchased from a different shop)

Comment: Don't worry about the brand, look for `-R` `+R` `RW' these must be compatible with your drive. Then consider how they where stored.